# Authorize a User via command line in Doorkeeper

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, doorkeeper

Is it possible to authorize a User for an Application using the Rails console, or even model code?

In certain situations, I want to be able to create and authorize a new user account for a particular application.

Essentially I want to be able generate an authorization_code on the command line.

Answer (score 1):

You need to disable the confirmation feature for the app owner:

$ app = Doorkeeper::Application.new :name => 'test', :redirect_uri => 'http://test.com'
$ app.owner = User.last # Or any owner class that you want to be associated
$ app.save

Take a look on the [documentation](https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper/wiki/Associate-users-to-OAuth-applications-(ownership)) for further details.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure its the best way to do it, but by manually creating a Doorkeeper::AccessGrant, with the proper associations you can get an authorization code from it.