# Authorize application, code level without hitting browser [Doorkeeper]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, doorkeeper

I found a related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16408723/authorize-a-user-via-command-line-in-doorkeeper) with no satisfactory answer, so asking here again:

I'm using [Doorkeeper](https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper) GEM for API calls for my application. I have followed the steps given in [oauth2](https://github.com/intridea/oauth2) gem docs:

```
require 'oauth2'
client = OAuth2::Client.new('client_id', 'client_secret', :site => 'https://example.org')

client.auth_code.authorize_url(:redirect_uri => 'http://localhost:8080/oauth2/callback')
```

As we see the last line execution gives a URL to be used in browser and get **authorization code** after clicking "**Authorize**".

But, I want to do all these in Rails model level, so that I don't have to hit the browser for **authorization code** and it should internally get the code which I can use later for token generation.

Is it possible?

Comment: In the normal OAuth flow, you redirect your user to the OAuth provider's site to sign in. On successfully signing in the user is then redirected back to your application with the code that you then swap for an access token. Do you have Doorkeeper set up to provide an access token using a different OAuth2 method?

Comment: @philnash Now I have change my method from **auth_code** to **implicit** but still it redirects me to login page if not logged in. I would like to create a user session internally by passing user credentials, to directly get the token

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you want to use the resource owner password credentials flow for OAuth2. It is best described how to set this up with Doorkeeper and the OAuth2 gem [in the Doorkeeper wiki](https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper/wiki/Using-Resource-Owner-Password-Credentials-flow).

Comment: Thanks but using this method throws me **OAuth2::Error: invalid_grant: The provided authorization grant is invalid, expired, revoked, does not match the redirection URI used in the authorization request, or was issued to another client.**

Comment: Anyways, It got fixed. Thanks

Comment: Cool, what was the issue?

Comment: I needed **current_account** id in my params as well, as many users belonging to diff accounts may have same email and diff passwords. Passing it in params solved it.